# Perl Script to Get Python's Version

Tags: linux, perl, parsing, command, version

Is there an easy way to get the version of python from a perl script. E.g. Get the equivalent of the version `python -V`. I need this to determine if I need to run `python26` or just `python` on some of my linux boxes.

If there isn't an easy way, I plan to run the `python -V` then capture stdout and parse it.

Comment: You could try to use exec() or system() to invoke python -V, not sure about how to redirect the output though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute any system command and capture STDOUT with [qx](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $v = qx(python -V);
print $v;
```

Comment: I'll probably use this and something like `if (index($str, "2.6.") != -1) { ...; } ` to check after that. I'll accept your answer once the wait period is done.

Comment: A similar approach: `perl -E 'chomp( $v = qx{ python -c "import platform; print platform.python_version()" }); say $v'` ->
2.7.2

Comment: @VenomFangs or use regex `if ($str =~ /\Q2.6./) {..}`